# Restrict access to webpage from single referrer domain using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to restrict access to a website to only allow referrers from a single domain. I can't get the .htaccess file to work correctly.
Say I am referring from http://domainname.com - access will be allowed.
Or http://subdomain.domainname.com - access will be allowed.

But any other referrer (or typing in URL) will block, and direct to Access Denied page.

Code as follows (note I need to allow access from ANY referrer page on domainname.com

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# allow these referers to passthrough
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(protect|unprotected)\.domainname\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# everybody else receives a forbidden
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

ErrorDocument 403 /forbidden.html
```

Comment: We need to see your code... Can't help without it.

Comment: Please add your code to the question ([edit](/posts/38975240/edit) button) and delete the comment - can't read code in comments.

Comment: And what is the problem - is it granting access to other referrers? You might want to deleting the first RewriteRule, but you must add a negator before the referrer URL: `!^http:...`.

Comment: No it seems to be blocking my allowed referrer as well.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP referer header only says were the request is coming from. E.g. when there is a link in some webpage from `www.example.net`

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/some/path>Click here</a>
```

then the request will be for `http://www.example.com/some/path` and the referer header will contain the URI from `www.example.net`.

If you block any request without a specific referer, then any direct request will be blocked too. Also note, that the referer header is sent by the client and therefore, it is not a reliable indicator.

Another caveat is, according to [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content- 5.5.2 Referer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.5.2), the client may send a `partial-URI`, which doesn't contain a domain name at all.

---

To answer your question, if you want to allow requests coming from either `domainname.com` or any of its subdomain, you might check for

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:.*\.)?domainname\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

or the other way round, forbid when you negate it

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(?:.*\.)?domainname\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

---

To check for one of multiple conditions, cond1 or cond2 or cond3, you must use [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) with the `ornext|OR` flag, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:.*\.)?nature\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:.*\.)?adclick\.g\.doubleclick\.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:.*\.)?onepointedpixel\.com
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Works from a test URL, but when I click from client banner ad it fails. (Banner click goes via an ad click URL, could this be causing an issue?)
Should allow access from all the URLs in the list, deny everything. But I do want to allow user to do page refreshes.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:.*\.)?nature\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:.*\.)?      adclick\.g\.doubleclick\.net
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(?:.*\.)?onepointedpixel\.com

RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ - [F]`

Comment: I wanted to also ask: do I need to specify the referring document on the referring domain, or just the domain, so if my referrer is 
http://www.nature.com/nrg/index.html?test=ads 
do I need to specify the whole URL?

Comment: You can check for whatever you like, this is just a regular expression. When the regex matches, the condition is true, when the regex does not match, the condition is false. It depends on what you want to achieve. Also, when you have multiple `RewriteCond`s, the conditions must all be true. If you want to match only one of them, you must use the `[OR]`, see [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: Thanks Olaf. Sorry this is not my area of expertise... if I want to check IF url1 is true OR url2 is true OR url3 is true, what is the syntax?